# Prove for any given positive integer $N$ there exist only finitely many integers n with $φ(n)=N$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove for any given  positive integer $N$ there exist only finitely many integers $n$ with $φ(n)=N$, where $φ$ denotes Euler’s $φ$-function. Conclude in particular that $φ(n)$ tend to infinity as n tend to infinity.

How can I prove the above statement? Because Euler’s $φ$-function is bijection?

Comment: Hint: Consider the prime factorization of $N$ and compute $\varphi(N)/N$.

Comment: Well, no: it is **not** a bijection, otherwise that you should prove.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $N$ be a positive integer, $p$ be the least prime greater than $N+1$, and $n$ be any integer such that $\varphi(n) = N$. We now show that there are finitely many such $n$:

If $q \geq p$ is a prime divisor of $n$, then $n = q^{k}m$ for some $k, m \geq 1$ and $gcd(q^{k}, m) = 1$. Furthermore, $\varphi (n) = \varphi (q^{k}) \varphi (m) \geq q-1$ since $\varphi (m) \geq 1$ and $\varphi (q^{k}) = q^{k-1}(q - 1) \geq q - 1$. This leads us to a contradiction; for $q-1 \geq p-1 \geq N$. Thus, no prime divisor of $n$ is greater than $N+1$. In particular, the distinct prime divisors of $n$ belong to a finite set, say $\{p_1, p_2, .., p_m\}$.

Now, consider the prime decomposition of $n$, $p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_n^{a_n}$, then $\varphi(n) = \varphi(p_1^{a_1})\varphi(p_2^{a_2})...\varphi(p_m^{a_m})$. Thus, we have $\varphi(n) = \prod_{i = 1}^m p_i^{a_i-1}(p_i - 1)$. Note that, if $p^k$ is a factor of $n$, then $p^{k-1}$ must be a factor of $N$, which ultimately limits the possible values for $k$. Therefore, $n$ must be a product of a bounded set of primes, each raised to a bounded exponent; there are finitely many such $n$.

Finally, for each positive integer $N$, there is a largest integer $n$ with $\varphi(n) = N$. Thus, as $n$ approaches infinity, so does $\varphi(n)$.

Comment: I hope you'll find time to enlarge upon this link-only answer with a fuller explanation.

Comment: @hardmath why? The link contains a complete argument.

Comment: @vadim123 Why? It answers the question.

Comment: This link might be gone in a week but the question may last forever.  Link-only answers are discouraged on Math.SE.  If you don't want to summarize the link's solution, then you should leave the link as a comment.

Comment: For fillers, you can use `{}{}{}...{}{}` where the dots just indicate you place enough of them to fill the space needed.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thanks! I personally think the whole character limitation stupid, so this was partly my way to make my opinion known.

Comment: @vadim123 Do you think posterity will thank us now?

Comment: @IgorRivin: The [Help Center -> Answering](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) sets out guidelines, in particular to provide context for links.  In case the link goes bad, the most important idea from it should be quoted.

Comment: Vadim's right: if the link disappears (as it's happened some 48285048345549386759321 times in the past), the answer becomes completely useless. It should bring the actual stuff, jsut as it does now.

Comment: @IgorRivin, on behalf of posterity I wish to give you my warmest upvote.

Comment: @vadim123 I thank you and posterity (on second thought, what has posterity ever done for me? I am thanking just you).