# Doubts about a proof of the existence of a lower bound on $\varphi(n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I recently attempted to solve the following question (exercise 0.2.10 from Dummit & Foote - Abstract Algebra):

Prove for any given positive integer $N$ there exist only finitely many integers $n$ with $\varphi(n) = N$, where $\varphi$ denotes Euler’s $\varphi$-function. Conclude in particular that $\varphi(n)$ tends to infinity as $n$ tends to infinity.

I ended with something much similar to:

1. [Is there an integer $N>0$ such that $\varphi(n) = N$ has infinitely many solutions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912137/is-there-an-integer-n0-such-that-varphin-n-has-infinitely-many-solutio)
2. [Prove for any given positive integer $N$ there exist only finitely many integers n with $φ(n)=N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638381/prove-for-any-given-positive-integer-n-there-exist-only-finitely-many-integers/638385#638385)

Which show that, for any given $N$, there are finitely many $n$ such that $\varphi(n) = N$. I am *OK* with this. However, the question also asks whether $\varphi(n)$ tends to infinite as $n$ does; 2. attempts to conclude that from 1, and that *doesn't* feel right to me. Let me explain:

All answers reach a point where for $\varphi(n) = N$, then $n$ must be a product of finitely many bounded primes, each raised to a bounded exponent. However, nothing is said about a lower bound on such $n$, and thus it seems wrong to conclude that $N$ grows with $n$; what if $N$ oscillates without a lower bound as $n$ grows bigger? The argument doesn't seem to address this possibility.

I know that $\varphi(n)$ is in fact bounded below, and many good answers can be found here: [Is the Euler phi function bounded below?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301837/is-the-euler-phi-function-bounded-below)

What I ask, then, is whether that conclusion is false, needs some tinkering to work, or is fine and I missed something.

Comment: $\varphi(n)$ is a function on the natural numbers so it can be viewed as a sequence. What is the definition of $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\varphi_n = \infty$? Can you prove the statement using the definition directly and the fact that there are only finitely many $n$ such that $\varphi(n) = N$ for any $N$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conclusion is fine. From the observation that the solution set of $\varphi(x) = N$ is finite for each fixed $N$, it follows that $\varphi$ does not "oscillate" like that. The proof follows, so skip the rest if you'd like to work it out yourself!

Recall that the sequence $\varphi$ tends to infinity precisely if for any $M \in \mathbb{R}$ we can find an integer $K$ such that for all $n > K$, $a_n > M$.

So take any number $M$. There are finitely many integers $i$ that lie between $0$ and $M$. We know by our observation that for each of these finitely many integers $i$ the solution set of the equation $\varphi(x) = i$ is itself finite. But the union of finitely many finite sets is still finite, so there are finitely many solutions to $\varphi(i) \leq M$. The finite set of solutions has a maximal element, denote it $K$. Now for all $n > K$, $n$ is not a solution to $\varphi(n) \leq M$, so in fact we have $\varphi(n) > M$.

Comment: Just got it! I should have thought about it for a little longer; thanks for the disclaimer though.